# How to convert a string to ISO-8859-2 format using JMeter(Groovy or Beanshell)

Tags: jmeter

I have a string "Urząd" with polish characters.
How to convert string in ISO-8859-2 format using JMeter(Groovy or Beanshel) ?
Expected value after conversion is Urz%B1d. Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class provides [`encode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function which takes charset as the second argument

```
URLEncoder.encode('Urząd','ISO-8859-2')
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Hi , I have tried it but it is returning 2023-01-20 12:08:07,843 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[#650,Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
org.codehaus.groovy.GroovyBugError: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Script208.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 63
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:905) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]

Comment: It works with Groovy JMeter 5.5, where we have Groovy 3.0.11. Thanks

Comment: file major version 63 means that you're using [Java 19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout), it might be the case you're using a JMeter version which comes with Groovy which doesn't support Java 19 yet. Try upgrading to latest JMeter ([JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) as of now) and if you will still be experiencing the problem you will have to downgrade your Java. In any case [it's recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)